# Bash script says it has invalid option on my terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I have a shell script that has the following in shebang:

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1 node --experimental-json-modules
```

When I run the script, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/env: invalid option -- 'S'
Try '/usr/bin/env --help' for more information.
```

I confirmed that when I run this script on another machine which has a bash terminal, it works fine. I am fairly new to bash internals. What am I missing?

Bash version I am running:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
  4.4.20(1)-release
```

Comment: just remove the `-S` to `/usr/bin/env NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1 node --experimental-json-modules`

Comment: Also, what do you get from `/usr/bin/env --version`

Comment: Check `/usr/bin/env --version` on both the computer it works on, and the one it fails on. `/usr/bin/env --help` (as mentioned in the error message) might also be informative.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759460/executing-node-js-file-in-a-bash-script) could be better to avoid [portability issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Character_interpretation) like this one.

Comment: Why do you think the version of `bash` is relevant? The error is coming from `env`, not `bash`.

Comment: | The -P, -S,-u and -v options are non-standard extensions supported by FreeBSD, but which may not be available on other operating systems.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env ` <> `bash`!  Your first line should probably be `#!/bin/bash`; *NOT* what you have!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, removing the -S option was a workaround. But I just ended up updating my linux coreutils to 8.30. 8.30 added support for `-S`. So, now not only does this script work for me but I am running the latest version of the build. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
#! /usr/bin/env NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1 node --experimental-json-modules
```

would do the same.